# How to translate a costume post type?

Tags: wordpress

I can't figure out why it won't translate Custom Post Type names. It changes the name, but it doesn't depend on which language is on the website. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong, I'm starting to lose my mind)

```
function dev_change_post_object() {
    global $wp_post_types;
 
    $labels = &$wp_post_types['chip']->labels;
    
    $locale = get_locale();
    
    if ( $locale == 'en_US' ) {
        $labels->name = 'Chips';
        $labels->singular_name = 'Chip';
        $labels->add_new = 'Add Chip';
        $labels->add_new_item = 'Add Chip';
        $labels->edit_item = 'Edit Chip';
        $labels->new_item = 'Chip';
        $labels->view_item = 'View Chip';
        $labels->search_items = 'Search Chip';
        $labels->not_found = 'No Chip found';
        $labels->not_found_in_trash = 'No Chip found in Trash';
        $labels->all_items = 'All Chip';
        $labels->menu_name = 'Chip';
        $labels->name_admin_bar = 'Chip';
    } else {
        $labels->name = 'Чіпи';
        $labels->singular_name = 'Чіп';
        $labels->add_new = 'Додати чіп';
        $labels->add_new_item = 'Додати новий чіп';
        $labels->edit_item = 'Редагувати чіп';
        $labels->new_item = 'Чіп';
        $labels->view_item = 'Переглянути чіп';
        $labels->search_items = 'Пошук чіпа';
        $labels->not_found = 'Чіп не знайдено';
        $labels->not_found_in_trash = 'Не знайдено в кошику чіпу';
        $labels->all_items = 'Всі чіпи';
        $labels->menu_name = 'Чіп';
        $labels->name_admin_bar = 'Чіп';
    }
}

add_action( 'init', 'dev_change_post_object' );
```

Comment: Aren't these suppose to be like: `__('Chips', 'text-domain');`? https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/__/

Comment: This doesn't work either 
`
function dev_change_post_object() {
    global $wp_post_types;
 
    $labels = &$wp_post_types['chip']->labels;
 
 $locale = get_locale();
 
 if ( $locale == 'en_US' ) {
  $labels->name = __('Chips', 'text-domain');
  $labels->singular_name = __('Chip', 'text-domain');
  $labels->add_new = __('Add Chip', 'text-domain');
 } else {
  $labels->name = __('Чіпи', 'text-domain');
  $labels->singular_name = __('Чіп', 'text-domain');
  $labels->add_new = __('Додати чіп', 'text-domain');
 }
}
add_action( 'init', 'dev_change_post_object' );

`